# Use Sed/Awk to fix faulty SRT files

Tags: script, sed, awk

Recently I downloaded some badly formated SRT files, having the time format messed up as

```
HH:MM:SS:XXX
```

whereas it should be

```
HH:MM:SS,XXX
```

The main problem now is to replace the third colon with a comma in every timing line formatted as

```
HH:MM:SS,XXX --> HH:MM:SS,XX
```

Can anyone suggest a sed/awk script to fix this problem in the entire file?
I did try

```
sed 's/:/,/3;s/:/,/5' file
```

but it didn't seem to work

**Edit:** 
Answered my own question, having forgotten all about backreferences

```
sed -E "s/([0-9][0-9])(:)([0-9][0-9][0-9])/\1,\3/g"
```

Comment: Please post your answer below as a *real* answer. You can then even accept it later.

Answer (score 1):

Tell sed to replace a colon that is not followed by any more colons:

```
sed 's/:\([^:]\+\)$/,\1/'
```

Comment: Works, but only for the last timing. I get HH:MM:SS:XXX --> HH:MM:SS,XX (first colon remains unchanged)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the third and sixth occurrence of colon on lines containing `-->` works here:

```
sed '/-->/ { s/:/,/6; s/:/,/3 }'
```

Do it in reverse so the occurrence order is kept.

Answer (score 0):

Replace anything that matches colon+digits+end-of-line into command+what-was-found

```
sed  's/:([0-9]*)$/,\1/' file
```